# How to use parameters from previous builds in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a job with a file parameter that I want to run on a schedule. I want to upload the files once and have jenkins continue to use the files for all future builds. Is this possible without writing my own plugin? I am aware of the managed scripts plugin, this does not do what I need. The point is to be able to have users upload files to the workspace and set them to run on a schedule. Even simpler would be to have a run uploaded file in a build step. Is there a plugin that does this?

To be clear, I want to upload shell scripts and use them in build steps on a scheduled job. Setting a file parameter is the closest I could get, but the parameter is wiped after each build and the file has to be re-uploaded. I am using Jenkins primarily to manage scripts for a team. Copy pasting is a pain in the ass and we want to be able to upload via a dialogue and then set the script to run.

Comment: Could you let us know more details about how you envision this to work? Do you want them to upload using Jenkins (limiting them to the workspace of the current job) or using for example `rsync` to put something in an arbitrary location on the server? Are they uploading code, compiled binaries, test data or just arbitrary files? Do you want each user to have access to all the files or only "their" files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to keep files that drive Jenkins jobs (scripts or config files) in version control, possibly near the project they are related to - but that's just me.

To create a workflow that you described, I would use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) like this:

1. Create job A with the file parameter, upload it in the way you imagined, and archive it in a post-build step
2. In job B (and others), use the copy artifact build step to copy the file from job A - you can specify either to copy it directly from the workspace (in that case you don't even need to archive it), or to get an artifact e.g. from the last successful build.

You could also fingerprint the file in all jobs where it was used - that way Jenkins will also know the relation between each build (in case you want to track down what version of the file was used for a specific build).

Another solution could be the [Copy Data To Workspace Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Data+To+Workspace+Plugin), with this you can copy files from the Jenkins master at the beginning of a build, by default from `JENKINS_HOME/userContent` - though in this case you would need to place the file on the master in advance.

Comment: This seems like a good option...are you sure there is no way to just upload files to the workspace when creating the project?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but what I get between lines is that you want a mechanism to run a Jenkins job as per a particular schedule that will be defined by you.

If this is what you want to know then in the "Build Triggers" option of Jenkins, there is a check-box for "Build Periodically".

[image]

You can define a cron expression to run on a particular schedule.
For example: 
1.) every fifteen minutes:   **H/15 * * * ***
2.) every ten minutes in the first half of every hour:  **H(0-29)/10 * * * ***
3.) once every two hours every weekday:  **H 9-16/2 * * 1-5**
4.) once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December:  **H H 1,15 1-11 ***

If you need something else, then please specify some example. I would be able to understand better. :)

Comment: not really...I'm aware of how to run scripts on a schedule.

Comment: If you want to use some shell scripts that are needed in the build process, why do you need to upload it again and again. Keep them in any location where the Jenkins server is running. Use them directly without uploading them again and again.
About the parameter thing, I still don't get it..What parameters are you supplying and to which command/file?

Comment: I'm trying to provide an web interface for a user to upload shell scripts to the workspace, then access them from the project which is run on a schedule. Reading around, file parameters seems to be the only way to do this, but when I click "run with parameters" I have to upload the file each time, and there is no way to provide a default parameter.

Comment: What kind of default parameter you want to give? A directory location or a URL from where a file named, say hello.sh will be fetched?? Is it what you want?
If this is what needed, then I am afraid you will have to define a String parameter with default value and use "wget" in case of URL to fetch the file in your build process itself.

Comment: Yes, Once hello.sh is in the workspace, i would like to be able to access it every time.

So basically there is no way to upload shell scripts when creating a project, and then use them in the build each time? Lets say I have 10 complicated scripts. Do I have to create a build step for each file and copy-paste the file in?